# How to display a table in terminal stored in sql file using MySQL XAAMP?

Tags: mysql, database

How I can see the view the table of the data I have created in the SQL file?

I have downloaded XAAMP to access MySQL. Basically, I want to see a table in the terminal like show below:

[image]

First, through the terminal, I went into the path of SQL folder and typed 'mysql -u root test < fileName.sql'. I am aware that typing this code allows the creation of the table.

Then, I typed 'mysql -u root' to access the main menu of the database, which shows like this:

[image]

I understand there's is a bunch of codes I can execute from here (ex. 'show databases;', 'use tests;'), but I'm having difficulty understanding which code to use to display a table I have created in the .sql file.

Here is my SQL code:

```
create table employee (
  ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name varchar(100),
  last_name varchar(100),
  employee_id varchar(100),
  phone_number varchar(100),
  workstation varchar(100),
  security_level varchar(100),
  work_experience varchar(100),
  sales_record varchar(100),
  work_hour varchar(100),
  gender varchar(100),

  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

insert into employee (first_name, last_name, employee_id, phone_number, workstation, security_level, work_experience, sales_record, work_hour, gender) values ('michael',  'jackson', '12321', '778223123', 'West Wing','Level 3', '5 years', '240 sales/month', '8AM-5PM', 'male');
insert into employee (first_name, last_name, employee_id, phone_number, workstation, security_level, work_experience, sales_record, work_hour, gender) values ('jason',  'ahn', '32183', '2364382954', 'North-South Wing','Level 1', '2 years', '80 sales/month', '8AM-4PM', 'male');
insert into employee (first_name, last_name, employee_id, phone_number, workstation, security_level, work_experience, sales_record, work_hour, gender) values ('emily',    'carr', '12321', '7781232134', 'West Wing','Level 3', '5 years', '240 sales/month', '8AM-5PM', 'female');
insert into employee (first_name, last_name, employee_id, phone_number, workstation, security_level, work_experience, sales_record, work_hour, gender) values ('patrick', 'storm', '89231', '7782931232', 'South-West Wing','Level 2', '3 years', '118 sales/month', '8AM-5PM', 'male');
insert into employee (first_name, last_name, employee_id, phone_number, workstation, security_level, work_experience, sales_record, work_hour, gender) values ('elizabeth', 'young', '82931', '778291324', 'North Wing','Level 1', '6 years', '300 sales/month', '8AM-3PM', 'female');
insert into employee (first_name, last_name, employee_id, phone_number, workstation, security_level, work_experience, sales_record, work_hour, gender) values ('taylor', 'savier', '21321', '6045842132', 'West Wing','Level 2', '2 years', '140 sales/month', '8AM-6PM', 'female');
insert into employee (first_name, last_name, employee_id, phone_number, workstation, security_level, work_experience, sales_record, work_hour, gender) values ('jordan', 'johnson', '27312', '2364832912', 'East Wing','Level 3', '8 years', '210 sales/month', '8AM-4PM', 'male');
insert into employee (first_name, last_name, employee_id, phone_number, workstation, security_level, work_experience, sales_record, work_hour, gender) values ('elizabeth', 'young', '82931', '778291324', 'North Wing','Level 1', '6 years', '300 sales/month', '8AM-3PM', 'female');
insert into employee (first_name, last_name, employee_id, phone_number, workstation, security_level, work_experience, sales_record, work_hour, gender) values ('elizabeth', 'young', '82931', '778291324', 'North Wing','Level 1', '6 years', '300 sales/month', '8AM-3PM', 'female');
insert into employee (first_name, last_name, employee_id, phone_number, workstation, security_level, work_experience, sales_record, work_hour, gender) values ('elizabeth', 'young', '82931', '778291324', 'North Wing','Level 1', '6 years', '300 sales/month', '8AM-3PM', 'female');
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Just edited the tag.

Comment: type ```SHOW DATABASES;``` to list available databases, then ```USE databasename;```, then ```SHOW TABLES;``` to list tables inside databasename, then ```DESC tablename``` to show table's data type/structure, then ```SELECT * FROM tablename``` to display table's data

Answer (score 0):

well i dont know how to show them in XAMPP but I know how to show the tables and its data in the terminal .

> > SHOW TABLES;
> > ##this shows the tables you have in the database

> > SELECT * FROM table_name;
> > ##this line will display all the rows and columns of the chosen table